# Firebase Database Design

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database containing a structure similar to the one shown below. Since I am not allowed to make it public I am using the following keys:

1. *i = {0,1,2,3....}*
2. All `a(i)` represent single *key/value* pairings e.g. `userName: "awesome"`

With the below structure, every time a `User` wants to create new `Stuff` these are the steps I currently take

1. Store images to `FIRStorage` and retrieve their respective `downloadURL`
2. Then I add the `Stuff` to `FIRDatabase`. At this point I add all of the info related to `a(i)` because they're all under a single child; `Stuff.UUID`, hence I send one huge dictionary consisting of the data.

The issue arises in adding data to the mini-dictionaries. Because they are in different paths, I have to individually make requests to all of them as shown below

3. I then add `location` info
4. Followed by the respective child of `timeStamp`
5. The `images` information is next to be updated
6. Subscribe the `User` to respective `Stuff.UUID`
7. Lastly add the `User.UUID` to the members portion of `Stuff`

Is it possible to reduce steps 3-7?

As a follow up, is it possible to add values into different paths with one call?

**PS:** [Link](http://pastebin.com/adfCJhq2) to what the code of the above demo might look like. Due to confidentiality stuff I am not allowed to post the actual code.

```
{
   "Users":
   {
     "JglJnGDXcqLq6m844pZ":
     {
        a(0),
        a(1),
        a(2),
        a(3),
        a(4),
        a(5),

        "Stuff":
        {
           "fcWpzduhpPn8XR6Zqca": true,
           "gfntTr6TkDwZ439jkW8": true
        }
      }
    },

   "Stuff":
   {
      "fcWpzduhpPn8XR6Zqca":
      {
         a(0),
         a(1),
         a(2),
         a(3),
         a(4),
         a(5),
         a(6),
         a(7),

         "location":
         {
            "latitude":"-17.41439",
            "longitude":"-5.85170"
         },

         "timestamp":
         {
            "created":
            {
               a(0),
               a(1),
               a(2),
               a(3),
               a(4),
               a(5),
             },
             "lastModified":
             {
               a(0),
               a(1),
               a(2),
               a(3),
               a(4),
               a(5),
             }
          },
          "images":
          {
             "B4FaR6wfJAeXqJ29T33":
             {
               "imageURL": "https://google.com"
             }
          },
          "members":
          {
             "JglJnGDXcqLq6m844pZ": true,
             "DpHAfrqL4eqbR8QNgHg": true
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Are [multi-location updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) what you looking for?

Comment: @AndréKool Thanks a lot mate!